# TextCommandBarFlyout style

Tags: c#, xaml, textbox, contextmenu, winui-3

How can I customize the style of [TextCommandBarFlyout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/winui/api/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.textcommandbarflyout?view=winui-3.0) context menu control (which is the default context for `TextBox`, `PasswordBox`, etc.)?

Or how can I get the style of `TextCommandBarFlyout` which is used in `Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Command bar flyout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/controls/command-bar-flyout):

> TextCommandBarFlyout can't be customized, and is managed automatically by each text control. However, you can replace the default TextCommandBarFlyout with custom commands.

So you can't adjust the style of TextCommandBarFlyout.